# Matrix Products with Angles

Tags: matrices, geometry, trigonometry

> Verify that
>   $$
> \left[\begin{matrix}\cos32 & -\sin32\\
> \sin32 & \cos32
> \end{matrix}\right]\cdot\left[\begin{matrix}\cos40 & -\sin40\\
> \sin40 & \cos40
> \end{matrix}\right]=\left[\begin{matrix}\cos72 & -\sin72\\
> \sin72 & \cos72
> \end{matrix}\right]
> $$
>   and explain why this result could have been expected.

I have verified that the product matrix is correct using the matrix operation techniques, but I am not sure as to why the result is expected.

Comment: https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rotation_matrix

Comment: Did you verify only numerically? If so, are you aware of the [angle addition identities](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_trigonometric_identities#Angle_sum_and_difference_identities)?

Answer (score 5):

The matrix

$$R\left(\theta\right)=\begin{pmatrix}\cos\theta&-\sin\theta\\\sin\theta&\cos\theta\end{pmatrix}$$

when acted on a vector, rotates the vector by an angle $\theta$. Thus it is expected that a rotation by $\theta_{1}$, followed by a rotation by $\theta_{2}$, will be equivalent to a rotation by $\theta_{1}+\theta_{2}$. In matrix notation this is translated into

$$R\left(\theta_{1}\right)R\left(\theta_{2}\right)=R\left(\theta_{1}+\theta_{2}\right)$$

Comment: I don't quite understand what is meant by $\theta_1$ and $\theta_2$?

Comment: @geo_freak Just two angles.

Comment: [+1] Thorough explanation. In your last sentence, you need a translation to explain a rotation ... :)

Comment: Maybe the OP could have a look at (https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/363652/understanding-rotation-matrices)

Answer (score 2):

In addition to the comment above, I think it deserves a little explaination why: $R\left(\theta_{1}\right)R\left(\theta_{2}\right)=R\left(\theta_{1}+\theta_{2}\right)$

By using matrix multiplication we get:

$$R\left(\theta_{1}\right)R\left(\theta_{2}\right)=\begin{pmatrix}\cos\theta_{1}&-\sin\theta_{1}\\\sin\theta_{1}&\cos\theta_{1}\end{pmatrix}\cdot\begin{pmatrix}\cos\theta_{2}&-\sin\theta_{2}\\\sin\theta_{2}&\cos\theta_{2}\end{pmatrix} = \begin{pmatrix}\cos\theta_{1}\cos\theta_{2}-\sin\theta_{1}\sin\theta_{2} & -\left(\sin\theta_{1}\cos\theta_{2}+\cos\theta_{1}\sin\theta_{2}\right)\\
\sin\theta_{1}\cos\theta_{2}+\cos\theta_{1}\sin\theta_{2} & -\sin\theta_{1}\sin\theta_{2}+\cos\theta_{1}\cos\theta_{2}
\end{pmatrix}$$

We will use the trigonometric identities:

$$\left(1\right) \cos\left(\theta_{1}+\theta_{2}\right)=\cos\theta_{1}\cos\theta_{2}-\sin\theta_{1}\sin\theta_{2}\\
  \left(2\right) \sin\left(\theta_{1}+\theta_{2}\right)=\sin\theta_{1}\cos\theta_{2}+\cos\theta_{1}\sin\theta_{2}$$
And we will  recieve:
$$R\left(\theta_{1}\right)R\left(\theta_{2}\right)=\begin{pmatrix}\cos\theta_{1}\cos\theta_{2}-\sin\theta_{1}\sin\theta_{2} & -\left(\sin\theta_{1}\cos\theta_{2}+\cos\theta_{1}\sin\theta_{2}\right)\\
\sin\theta_{1}\cos\theta_{2}+\cos\theta_{1}\sin\theta_{2} & -\sin\theta_{1}\sin\theta_{2}+\cos\theta_{1}\cos\theta_{2}
\end{pmatrix}=\begin{pmatrix}\cos\left(\theta_{1}+\theta_{2}\right) & \sin\left(\theta_{1}+\theta_{2}\right)\\
\sin\left(\theta_{1}+\theta_{2}\right) & \cos\left(\theta_{1}+\theta_{2}\right)
\end{pmatrix} = R\left(\theta_{1}+\theta_{2}\right)$$
As said in the comment above.

Comment: I think this has been done by the OP. What is lacking him/her (see the last sentence of the question) is to know in which way the result could have been anticipated. There, a geometrical understanding is necessary (see the answer of @erenreches).

Comment: It might be obvious for him, but for future reference, other people might come and look for the same answer and be puzzled why $R\left(\theta_{1}\right)+R\left(\theta_{2}\right)=R\left(\theta_{1}+\theta_{2}\right)$. So it won't hurt to show the algebraic reasoning behind the rotation.

Comment: I accept your argument. Nevertheless, his question was elsewhere.